# PyDev (Eclipse) unhandled exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pydev_notify_kill'

Tags: python, eclipse, multithreading, debugging, pydev

For a few hours now PyDev (installed inside Eclipse) throws some weird error at me:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <_pydev_bundle.pydev_monkey._NewThreadStartupWithTrace instance at 0x0423E918>
27.06.2018 04:44:34 ERROR     <<< UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION >>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.4.1.201806231219\pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey.py", line 617, in __call__
    global_debugger.notify_thread_created(thread_id, t)
  File "C:\Users\...\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.4.1.201806231219\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 467, in notify_thread_created
    elif thread.additional_info.pydev_notify_kill:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pydev_notify_kill'
```

I am debugging [pyLoad](https://github.com/GammaC0de/pyload/tree/captcha-interactive) and I get this error and stack trace exactly when [this line](https://github.com/GammaC0de/pyload/blob/captcha-interactive/module/database/DatabaseBackend.py#L125) is executed. By inspecting the PyDev sources I found out that it has something to do with threads. Apparently PyDev tries to catch the creation of the new thread and start tracing it - but something in this proccess seems to go south.

Everything was working just fine a few hours ago, right before a few Python packages were striking and I had to reinstall my whole Python runtime and after that did several Eclipse and PyDev re-installations.

I'm using the latest Eclipse Oxygen.3A and PyDev 6.4.1.201806231219. I had my Eclipse/PyDev setup running stable for at least 2-2.5 years now so I can't really tell whether I had a similar problem back then and resolved it somehow. But right now I'm really lost and I hope one of you has any good idea on what could cause this. Maybe some simple setting of PyDev?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was also reported at the pydev issue tracker at:

https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/923

So, please refer to that ticket (the issue is already fixed for 6.4.2 and there's a solution you can use at that ticket while the new version is not released).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!